# Chrome error: -105 (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) xip.io

Tags: google-chrome, dns, xip.io

I frequently use xip.io to access local vagrant created VMs in VirtualBox on Windows 10. These are typically unroutable IPs, like this:

http://examplephpsite.192.168.76.10.xip.io/

More and more frequently Chrome is getting a DNS error that prevents me from accessing my page. From `chrome://net-internals/#dns` I see this error:

```
examplephpsite.192.168.76.10.xip.io IPV4    error: -105 (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)
```

I found a workaround here: https://superuser.com/questions/712855/err-name-not-resolved-in-chrome-on-a-single-site, but I now have to do this many times per day.

What is causing this error and is there some way to eliminate it so that my xip.io URLs always resolve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the suggestion to try http://nip.io/ as an alternative to xip.io, and it's working great. No more instability and I haven't had to clear my cache or flush DNS once while using nip.io.